# php-mysqlがインストールができない

Tags: php, mysql, centos

お世話になっております。
VPS環境にownCloudを実現すべく、php-mysqlをインストールしたいのですが、以下のようなエラーが出て困っております。

```
# yum install --enablerepo=remi php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
* extras: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
* remi: remi.kazukioishi.net
* updates: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
  Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.41-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
Package mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-libs-5.6.25-2.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.5.43-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686 (base)
           Not found
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

何か競合している？と考えているのですが対処方法が今ひとつ分かりません。
ご指南いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

インストール済みのパッケージは以下です。

```
CentOS release 6.6
　　　# rpm -qa | grep php
        php-cli-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-xml-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-mbstring-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-common-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-process-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-gd-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-ldap-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-pdo-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taichi Yanagiya さんのご回答で owncloud を利用するために`php-mysql`をインストールするという問題は解決できると思いますが、とりあえず動かしたい！ということであれば代替案として、一旦`php`と`mysql`の関連パッケージも`remove`してから owncloude の必要パッケージをまとめて入れなおしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
** CentOS6.X系で、レポジトリの準備とWebサーバ・ライブラリはインストールされているものとします **
// 関連パッケージの入れ直し
# yum remove php*
# yum remove mysql mysql-server mysql-lib
# yum install --enablerepo=remi php php-mysql php-pdo php-gd php-mbstring mod_ssl mysql-server mysql

// Owncloudのインストール
# yum install owncloud --enablerepo=isv_ownCloud_community,remi

// MySQLのセットアップ
# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
# chkconfig mysqld on
# mysql_secure_installation

// OwncloudのDB作成
# mysql -u root -p

// my.cnfの編集
# cp /usr/share/mysql/my-large.cnf /etc/my.cnf
# vi /etc/my.cnf
# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

ライブラリ系が不安であれば、`yum groupinstall "DevelopmentTools"`でまとめていれてしまうか、下記な感じで個別に確認してみてください。

```
//ライブラリのインストール
# yum install libzip libzip-devel zlib-devel libaio pcre pcre-devel gcc
```

Comment: SinoPen さん、ありがとうございます。 
補足すると、mysql-community-* が排他的に CentOS mysql-* も remi mysql-* も削除してしまうので、
remi よりバージョンの高い mysql-community-* をアンインストールしない限り、remi mysql-* がインストールできないと思います(すなわち、php-mysql の依存関係の問題はそのまま)。
あ、php-mysql 無しで owncloud を動かすということでしょうか？

Comment: Taichi Yanagiyaさん、補足ありがとうございます。自分でやった時は入ったと思ったのですが、仰る通り試すとダメでした。ですので、一連を試しなおして、入れ直し&owncloudeが動くように回答を直しました。決してphp-mysql 無しで owncloud を動かそうと思ったのではありませんw

Comment: 返信が遅れまして申し訳ありません。
提案していただいた通り、いったんPHP、MySQL、ownCloud関係のファイルをすべて削除してから(無論DBのバックアップは取った後)上記の方法でやり直したところうまくownCloudを動かすことができました。
今後のため躓いたところを残しておくと、”/etc/init.d/mysqld start”のところでうまく起動せず、ログファイルを見て”default-character-set = utf8は使えないよ”とあったので、my.cnfに”character-・・・・”と記載したのですがにいっこうに反映されません。そこで"yum remove"だけでなく”rm -rf /var/lib/mysql”で完全消去したのち、"rpm -qa | grep -i mysql"で完全に消えたことを確認してから、再度全部入れ直したところうまく起動しました。おそらくゴミファイル?が残っていたのかなと考えています。
最後までご指導いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

remi の php-mysql-5.4.41 が、以下の libmysqlclient のバージョンを必要とするようコンパイルされています。該当バージョンのライブラリは remi の mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi で提供されています。

```
$ yumdownloader --enablerepo=remi php-mysql
$ rpm -qpR php-mysql-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm | grep libmysql
libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
```

しかし、このサーバーでは既に mysql-community-libs-5.6.25-2.el6 (mysql.com の Community 版)がインストールされており、libmysqlclient_16 の提供が無くなっています。
mysql-community-libs と mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi は共存できません。
php-mysql をインストールしようとすると、libmysqlclient_16 が必要 → mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi が必要 → mysql-community-libs と共存できないためエラー、となります。

解決方法としては、このサーバー上(mysql-community-libs 環境)で SRPM (http://rpms.remirepo.net/SRPMS/php-5.4.41-1.remi.src.rpm)をビルドしインストールする方法が考えられます。
また、依存関係だけの問題であれば、以下の手順で mysql-libs の情報だけ rpmdb に反映させ、インストールすることができますが、実際に動作するかどうかはわかりません。

```
# yumdownloader --enablerepo=remi mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64
# rpm -ivh --justdb --force mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
# yum install --enablerepo=remi php-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Taichi Yanagiyaさん、回答ありがとうございます。
早速、まず後者の方法を実行したところインストール自体は成功したのですが、ownCloudは未だにmySqlを認識してくれませんでした。

そこで

```
#yum remove php-mysql
```

でいったん削除した後、前者の方法を試みようと、適当なフォルダで

```
# wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/SRPMS/php-5.4.41-1.remi.src.rpm
# rpmbuild --rebuild php-5.4.41-1.remi.src.rpm
```

と実行したところ

```
warning: user remi does not exist - using root
warning: group remi does not exist - using root
<------ 省略-------->

warning: group remi does not exist - using root
error: Failed build dependencies:
    bzip2-devel is needed by php-5.4.41-1.el6.x86_64
    curl-devel >= 7.9 is needed by php-5.4.41-1.el6.x86_64
    gmp-devel is needed by php-5.4.41-1.el6.x86_64
    httpd-devel >= 2.0.46-1 is needed by php-5.4.41-1.el6.x86_64
    pam-devel is needed by php-5.4.41-1.el6.x86_64
    openssl-devel is needed by php-5.4.41-1.el6.x86_64
    sqlite-devel >= 3.6.0 is needed by php-5.4.41-1.el6.x86_64
    <------ 省略-------->
```

と出てしまいうまくいきませんでした。
初歩的な操作が分からずエラーになってしまっているかもしれませんがご指南いただけると幸いです。

Comment: "パッケージ名 is needed" と出力されるパッケージを yum install ですべてインストールする必要があります。また、コンパイル中にさらに、ヘッダファイル／ライブラリ／コマンドが見つからないなどの
エラーが出る場合もあります。mysql-5.6.25 が必須でなければ、代替案として remi の mysql-5.5.44 を使う方法も考えられます。